# count view controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, view, uiviewcontroller, controllers

I can't seem to get the number of view controllers in the view controller stack.

```
NSUInteger *viewControllerCount = self.navigationController.viewControllers.count;
```

I can loop through the view controllers and NSLog the objects within but I can't do a simple count. If I try to access this pointer, the ap crashes... no Log, no error message, nada. Please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you want to remove the `*`:

```
NSUInteger viewControllerCount = self.navigationController.viewControllers.count;
```

Comment: Thanks Doug, that was what I was missing.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why this isn't working is because `NSUInteger` isn't an object type, it's a language type.

Therefore, you need to remove the `*` from the assignment and it should work just fine.